# Any problems that may happen if I give my Wi-Fi extender the same SSID (and password) as my router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-extender

I recently installed a Netgear EX3700 Wi-Fi extender. After finding a spot to install it, I changed the SSIDs to the one of my router. (Verizon Fios Quantum). No speed or interference problems.

Can you tell me any problems that may crop up with this config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this not a problem (actually this is wanted so your device can stay in the same WLAN without adding a second one - I assume this is also what you wanted).

However roaming between different AP cells might cause problems with some cheap/old AP and/or devices. But you can check this: when your device switches from one AP 1 to AP 2 as soon as the signal strength from AP 2 is better you should be all set. If not it might be more feasible to use different SSIDs and do the switch manually.

Comment: I checked it but it doesn't work, but disconnecting and reconnecting does switch to the closest cell

Comment: @MashoorAiyaan Just a guess, but try to assing different SSIDs, save both networks, and check if the roaming works better. Otherwise, the only other choice is to check if you can tweak the roaming by changing the thresholds (I haven't tried this myself, I'm not sure if this is possible at all with consumer-grade products or even with pro products) or use devices that have better support for automatic roaming between cells.

Comment: Maybe a script that does a dis/reconnect at low signal strengths would work as well.

Comment: How will I set the thresholds? Are you talking about wifi signal power?

Comment: Also, what percentage should I set it if the ISP installed at the back of the house in the basement. (The extender is mounted nearby on the 1st floor.)

Comment: What does  "assing different SSIDs" mean

Comment: Either signal power or signal quality, but I'm not sure if those setting are available at all, if they are it will be trail and error to find the right setting, since it depends on your particular layout. Assigning different SSIDs would mean to give AP1 a different SSID then AP2 has.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120854/discussion-between-mashoor-aiyaan-and-albin).